# Can you use dict[key] and function(key) interchangeably?

Tags: python

Can you use dict[key] and function(key) interchangeably? For example, I have a value that is either a `data: dict` or `function(key: str): -> str`. Then I want to get value using the same syntax. So far, my solution is a tertiary statement such as `value = data[key] if isinstanceof(data, dict) else fn(key)`. It would be great to use parens or bracket for both types.

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: that would literally take unsafe typing to new heights ! why would you want to do that?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom There's nothing inherently unsafe about it besides the fact that dictionaries are necessarily partial functions but so too can arbitrary python functions be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you can subclass `dict` and override `__call__` which exposes the API you want:

```
>>> class mydict(dict):
...     def __call__(self, i):
...         return self.__getitem__(i)
...
>>> m = mydict()
>>> m[1] = 2
>>> m(1)
2
```

I don't recommend this. If your function is read-only, you could also pass `dict.get` which is a method doing roughly what you want, returning `None` in the default case that your key isn't in the dictionary:

```
>>> d = {1:2}
>>> def fun(x, f):
...     return f(x)
...
>>> fun(1, d.get)
2
>>> fun(1, lambda x: x*x)
1
```

Comment: That's a great answer! data.get would be equivalent to function signature. My use case is ready only.